# Format Code (Strg K + D) in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

if I press <kbd>STRG</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> in VS2010 the code (e.g. HTML, ASPX) will be formatted and empty lines will be deleted.

If I use this shortcut in VS2012 the empty lines will not be deleted. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Isn't that something in the preferences? I.E. where you set how to treat whitespace when pasting.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following combination to auto format indentations of my code in VS2012.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all the code in a file to be formatted. Or you can select just a block of the code.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>  will format the code with proper indentations.

No deletion of empty lines though.