# How to auto format code indentations in VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, format, indentation, auto-indent

How to auto format code in VS2012 to save time typing and deleting spaces and tabs?

[image]

Comment: or just 'Ctrl - E, D' if your IDE is set up as mine is.

Comment: You can use only "Crtl + E, D". That's work on the entire document.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123479/format-code-strg-k-d-in-vs-2012 ...

Comment: Sorry. Re-Worded to match Stack Overflow format.

Comment: I tried "Ctrl + E, D" in my Visual Studio 2012, Update 2 installation, but nothing is happening. Probably I am missing some settings.

Comment: Keep getting negatives for this question. Should I delete it if it doesn't help anybody?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you are looking to format the code as you enter the text, there are some additional settings in **Tools\Options\Text Editor** area.

Since your example appears to be a config file (XML) look at the XML editor.

[image]

Otherwise, to format at any time, the suggestions from *@mitaka* and *@Xaruth* are good.

Be aware that the keystrokes to activate **Format Document** and **Format Selection** are different depending on what Development Settings you have active in Visual Studio.  To see which keystrokes are assigned to the command in your copy of VS look in the **Edit** menu.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I use the following combination to auto format indentations of my code in VS2012.

Unformatted code bock in web.config:
[image: Unformatted xml block]

**Ctrl + A** to select all the code in a file to be formatted in VS2012. Or you can select just a block of the code manually.

**Ctrl + K**, then **Ctrl + F** will format the code with proper indentations.

Formatted code block
[image]